# In Meteor how to pass entire object to template helper?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I currently have a template helper I am using to set the color of a table row, based on some logic. The helper requires several fields to make its determination.

```
<template name="files">
   .
   .
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each files}}
          <tr class="status" style="background-color:{{getStatusColor deleted_on changed_on created_on}}">
            <td>{{_id}}</td>               
            <td>{{created_on}}</td>
            <td>{{changed_on}}</td>
            <td>{{deleted_on}}</td>
          </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
```

And the (abbreviated) JS:

```
Template.files.helpers({
  /* returns background color for row based on file properties */
  getStatusColor: function(deleted_on, changed_on, created_on) {
     if(deleted_on)
       return foo...
     if(changed_on)
       return bar...
  }
});
```

This works great but it seems kind of cheesy that I need to pass each individual attribute. Is there a cleaner way to pass the entire object, and reference the attributes from within the helper? Something along the lines of:

```
<template name="files">
   .
   .
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each files}}
          <tr class="status" style="background-color:{{getStatusColor this}}">
            <td>{{_id}}</td>               
            <td>{{created_on}}</td>
            <td>{{changed_on}}</td>
            <td>{{deleted_on}}</td>
          </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </tbody>
```

And referencing the attributes instead in the helper like this:

```
Template.files.helpers({
  /* returns background color for row based on file properties */
  getStatusColor: function(obj) {
     if(obj.deleted_on)
       return foo...
     etc.
  }
});
```

I understand this would make the helper need to know more about the data object in question, but am curious if this is possible.

P.S. I'm quite new to Meteor, be gentle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just answered your own question. If you pass in `this` inside the `each` loop, it will pass in the whole object.

In template:

```
{{#each files}}
  <tr class="status" style="background-color:{{getStatusColor this}}">
    <td>{{_id}}</td>               
    <td>{{created_on}}</td>
    <td>{{changed_on}}</td>
    <td>{{deleted_on}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

On a client.js file:

```
Template.files.helpers({
  /* returns background color for row based on file properties */
  getStatusColor: function(file) {
     if(file.deleted_on)
       return foo...
     etc.
  }
});
```

Comment: Ha, you're right (guess I was too). My problem was an unrelated change I had made on the server-side pub around the same time that had made the field I was looking for unavailable. Silly mistake. Good to know this is possible. I didn't see "this" referenced in Meteor docs with regard to Template helpers, just took a guess it should work.